# Updating apk SHA1 differs even after using same keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-keystore, app-update

I have uploaded my app to Goggle Play few months back after signing it with a release keystore, I have stored that Keystore for future updation.
 Now I have updated the apk with some changes, while trying to upload the new apk signed with **same keystore** along with **same alias** and **password**, the apk is not allowed to upload to Goggle Play.
Playstore shows me following error : [image]

The only change is, earlier the appication was developed and build using **eclipse** and now in **android studio** 
 Can this be the reason for showing the above error???

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, Had to upload a new application all together with new package name and a new Keystore.

Comment: I have the same problem... But my is different. I can sign ma App in Android Studio 0.4.2, but I can't sign my App in new one (1.4.xxx). So I'm still develop in old one ;))) Funny....

Comment: @Jitu have a look at this link http://anandsekar.github.io/exporting-the-private-key-from-a-jks-keystore/

Comment: I also have same issue, and doesn't find out any solution for that.
Anybody here know solution for that, Please help us.

Comment: No solution found yet, we need to unpublish the current application, and add a new application

Comment: please check below answer

Comment: I know this is late and idk if it helps but for me the problem was just a wrong KeyAlias - double check these values.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message I would say you have mixed up the keystores, or android studio is just using the wrong one to do the release build. The best way to be completely sure is to clearly setup your build.gradle, and build it yourself on the command line using

```
 ./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

What is probably happening is that Android Studio is using your debug keystore (ie. the default) to sign the release build because it can't find the original keystore you used in eclipse, or you have the wrong password somewhere...

Have a look at this configuration, note the location of the keystores, the naming convention and how it corresponds to the build.gradle. Note the signingconfigs and how they are setup for the release build. To build from the command line, simply cd into the directory with your "gradlew" file, and run

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

to build the release apk, or

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

to build the debug apk. If it fails, try

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

[Screenshot of build.gradle and filesystem setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RItO.png)

But please remember not to put your keys in your source control! That means editing your .gitignore file.

There is a stack of information on how to do this here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html